# Applying two different sets of interest rates to two objects of the same class

Tags: java

**How can I make two objects of the same class use different interest rates?**

I need to make it so that savingAccount2 and savingAccount3 use different interest rates.

```
savingAccount1UI savingAccount2 = new savingAccount1UI();
savingAccount1UI savingAccount3 = new savingAccount1UI();
```

These objects both inherit from a class called Account.java. This superclass contains all the methods that include how to calculate the interest.

Here is the current method in the superclass that calculates the 1 year interest *account.java*:

```
//add interest
  public void interest(double interest){
      if(balance<target){

          interest = balance*lowRate; 
          balance = balance + interest;
          updatebalance();
      } else{
          interest=balance*highRate;
          balance = balance + interest;  
      }  
      updatebalance();
   }
```

Here is the button that triggers this method:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    interest(Float.parseFloat(balanceLabel.getText().substring(1)));
```

Currently I am using variables with double values assigned to them, but of course this means that both objects(savingAccount2 and savingAccount3) use the same numbers. Note that these variables are stored in the Account.java superclass Like so:

```
public double lowRate = 0.019;
public double highRate = 0.025;
```

I think I may need to use a constructor for each object, with pre-set values to solve my issue but I don't understand how to implement that idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write method in class Account to set the values of lowRate and highRate like:

```
public void setRates(double lr, double hr){
       lowRate=lr;
       highRate=hr;
}
```

Now when you create an object of class SavingsAccount, you can do:

```
SavingsAccount sa=new SavingsAccount();
sa.setRates(0.019,0.025);
```

Comment: Sorted. This answer solved my problem as it is easier to understand and implement into my program. Thanks for your knowledge and time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for this:

```
public class Account {

    private double lowRate;
    private double highRate;
    //other fields

    public Acount(double lowRate, double highRate) {
        this.lowRate = lowRate;
        this.highRate = highRate;
    }

    // your interest() method
    // getters & setters
}

public class SavingAccount1UI extends Account {

    public SavingAccount1UI(double lowRate, double highRate) {
        super(lowRate, highRate);
    }

    // rest of your stuff
}
```

This way you are only able to create an object passing the values you need, like:

```
SavingAccount1UI savingAccount = new SavingAccount1UI(0.019, 0.025);
```

Now every time you call your `interest()` method, it will take into consideration the values passed.

Comment: This seems to look like what i was researching. I will try to implement it soon and get back to you as I am currently on my moblilephone away from my computer. From what i have seen, it looks difficult to implement

Comment: It is extremely simple. Using constructors is a daily activity you will do in Java. just remember that you will call your method in your instances, like `savingAccount1.interest()`, `savingAccount2.interest()`, etc... Just lemme know if something wasn't clear.

Comment: Ok, so I understand the variable part... the bit below is what confuses me to be honest. I just dont know how I can implement it into my program beceause when I try to, I get lots of warning errors. For example, when I add the second part of the code to my account class, I get warning errors in my savingAccountUI1 class. To be specific, it has a problem with my 

"public savingAccount1UI() {
        initComponents();
        updatebalance();
    }"    @dambros

Comment: You cant have a constructor on the child class that doesn't match a super one. You are going to have to edit all constructors you had before. But honestly you should only need the one constructor I showed above.

Comment: To elaborate better: you can still use your constructor, but you are going to have to explicitly call super, because the compiler won't do it for you anymore since you have a custom super constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
savingAccount1UI savingAccount2 = new savingAccount1UI(0.019,0.025);
```

in class definition:

```
savingAccount1UI(float lowRate,float highRate) {
    this.lowRate = lowRate;
    this.highRate = highRate;
}
```

when computing pass also the class to the method and access the inners value.

```
public void interest(double interest,savingAccount1UI account){
  if(balance<target){

      interest = balance*account.lowRate; 
      balance = balance + interest;
      updatebalance();
  } else{
      interest=balance*account.highRate;
      balance = balance + interest;  
  }  
  updatebalance();
}
```